# Cannot import image into firebase-messaging-sw.js: "Cannot use import statements outside a module"

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got the "Cannot use import statements outside a module" when I tried to import an icon image into my firebase-messaging-sw.js file. I included '"type": "module"' in the package.json but still got the error.

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-messaging.js');
import icon from "../src/institutions/icon.jpeg";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...
  authDomain: ...
  databaseURL: ...
  projectId: ...
  storageBucket: ...
  messagingSenderId: ...
  appId: ...
  measurementId: ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  const title = "Hello world";
  const option = {
    body: "Hello world",
    icon: icon
  }
  return self.registration.showNotification(title, option);
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": ...,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  }
  ...
}
```